# Sencha Touch 2.3.1 + Phonegap 3.4 jsonp not working in Android but works on browser

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch

The following code works in the browser, I have also set-up the server to work with CORS according to this article: https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.loiane.com%2F2014%2F01%2Frequests-ajax-com-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-entre-sencha-touch-e-extjs-e-backend%2F

This is my model:

```
Ext.define('App.model.Jobs', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

        config: {
            fields: ['category','type','contact','contactn','date', 'title', 'email', 'descr', 'link']
        }
    });
```

This is the code to my store:

```
Ext.define('App.store.Jobs', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    requires: ['App.model.Jobs','Ext.data.proxy.JsonP'],
    config: {
        model: 'App.model.Jobs',
        storeId:'jobs',
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'https://app.com/app/api/api.php',useDefaultXhrHeader: false
            extraParams: {get: 'records', records: 'class'},
            reader: {type: 'json', rootProperty:'data'}
        },
        grouper: {
            groupFn: function(rec) {
                return rec.get('category');
            }, sortProperty: 'category'
        },
        autoLoad: true
    }
});
```

This is the code for my list:

```
Ext.define('App.view.Jobs', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'jobs',
    requires: ['Ext.field.Search'],
    config: {
        top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0, layout: 'card', fullscreen: true,
        items: [
            {xtype: 'list', title: 'Jobs Listing', grouped: true, indexBar: true, itemTpl: '{title}',
                listeners: {initialize: function() {
                        var store = Ext.getStore('jobs');
                        store.load();
                        this.setStore(store);
                    }}},
            {xtype: 'panel', animate: true, scrollable: {direction: 'vertical'}, tpl: 'Job Title:<br/>{title}<br/>Job Type: <br/>{type}<br/>Position:<br/>{position}<br/>Description:<br/>{descr}<br/>Deadline:<br/>{date}<br/>Contact Person:<br/>{contactn}<br/>Contact Number:<br/>{contact}<br/>Email:<br/>{email}<br/>URL:<br/>{link}'

            }
        ]
    }
});
```

When I run the code in my browser using the browser, it works fine. When I build it as a native app, it doesn't load anything.
I white-listed

```
<access origin="*"/>
```

I also tried converting the code to jsonP but still doesn't load anything on the native app but works fine in the browser

And this is my server code:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Android specifically, but I know when building iOS apps with Cordova I sometimes see errors logged in XCode that are helpful. Do you see anything here? I suspect CORS might fail because the referring "domain" doesn't exist when you're inside an Cordova app. You might try setting the CORS header to simply "*"

Comment: Hi, even setting up header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); doesn't seem to sort out the problem

Comment: Do you know if the request is making it outside the app and hitting the server or just the fact that nothing is loading in the app?

Comment: Hi, its a bit difficult to tell because when I add this url: 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&q=http://www.acme.com/jef/apod/rss.xml&num=20' it works fine. But when i use mine it doesn't load any records. It would have been easier if I could listen to success and failure events but the store seems to ignore listener events. Any suggestion on how I can force the store to listen to events?

Comment: I would try using Chrome's remote debugging feature to see if you can pinpoint any runtime errors.

Comment: I will try your suggestion

Answer (score -1):

After hours of fruitless research and redesigning the app I have finally found a solution. It turns out, each-time I added my url as thelink.com nothing was being returned except when I accidentally deleted the s and set it to thelink.com .I want to thank you all for the quick responses provided above that has made me learn a thing or two. Thanks for the support